# Sneaky ways to clone git repositories?

Tags: git, repository, clone

I'm working on a GHC port for Haiku, but I can't do "git clone" on the GHC repository because Haiku's git is borked.

Is there a way to clone a git repository without using git?

Answer (score 3):

You can clone a git repository without using git by copying ( rsync, scp whatever ) the `.git` ( or `.` in case of bare ) folder.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer, but I need an example, something like rsync http://darcs.haskell.org/ghc.git